# accordion not working using react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, components, react-bootstrap

I copy and paste the code from `"https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/"` but it does not work ..
[image]

[image]

```
<Accordion>
  <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
    <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #1</Accordion.Header>
    <Accordion.Body>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
      aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
      pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
      culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </Accordion.Body>
  </Accordion.Item>
  <Accordion.Item eventKey="1">
    <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #2</Accordion.Header>
    <Accordion.Body>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
      aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
      pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
      culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </Accordion.Body>
  </Accordion.Item>
</Accordion>
```

Comment: Could You provide link to the repo Please  or add all of Your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like maybe the dependent CSS is not properly imported for `react-bootstrap` components?

According to `react-bootstrap` [document](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#stylesheets), perhaps try add to `App.js`:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```